# Rails & Shoulda Spec Matcher: validate_presence_of (:first_name) blowing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

```
describe User do

  it { should belong_to(:shop) }


  it { should respond_to(:shop) }
  it { should respond_to (:first_name)}
  it { should respond_to (:last_name)}
  it { should respond_to (:email)}
```

Works fine. But as soon as I add:

```
it { should validate_presence_of (:first_name)}
it { should validate_presence_of (:last_name)}
```

It breaks, specifically in this callback method:

```
def get_url
    source = "http://www.randomsite.com/"+ first_name + "+" + last_name
end
```

> no implicit conversion of nil into String for +

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `first_name` and `last_name` are `nil` for the test.
Try to stub the values in a `before` block like this:

```
context 'first_name and last_name validation' do
  before do
    allow(subject).to receive(:first_name).and_return('bob')
    allow(subject).to receive(:last_name).and_return('tom')
  end

  it { should validate_presence_of (:first_name)}
  it { should validate_presence_of (:last_name)}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how `validate_presence_of(:first_name)` works:

1. It assigns `nil` to your model's `first_name` attribute and calls `.valid?` on your model.
2. If `.valid?` returns true - the test fails, since if you have had correct validation in place, that wouldn't happen.

I assume that `get_url` method is set up to run on `before_validation` callback, so what is going on in your code:

1. `first_name` gets assigned to `nil`.
2. `.valid?` is called.
3. `before_validation` callback fires your `get_url` method
4. Everything blows up, because `get_url` doesn't get into account that `first_name` can be `nil`.